# Google Play Console - can't publish to the closed testing - 1 unknown error

Tags: google-play-console

Close testing preview release:

[image]

The only step I didn't finish it's `Create a merchant account`. Do I need to finish it as well for Closed testing even if the app is going to be free and no in app purchases?

Dashboard:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the "Set up your app" questions, if you mentioned that your app is going to be paid, then you have to create a merchant account and if not, then you shouldn't. I personally have added an application to Closed Testing phase and it is a free app so I didn't have to create a Merchant account.
Also, a side note, if you add that your app is going to be free once, then you can't change it to paid but if you checked it paid then you can change it to free.